# inputCheckBox won't set from Apex

Tags: checkbox, salesforce, apex-code

I created an apex:dynamicComponent that creates checkboxes depending on stored data.

The creation of the checkbox is as follows :

```
Component.Apex.inputCheckbox chkBox = new Component.Apex.inputCheckbox();
if (myMap.get(myList[i]) == true) 
    chkBox.selected = true;
```

But when I try to display my VF page, it shows :

```
System.VisualforceException: Invalid value for property selected: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

I tried to set "chkBox.selected" with different values (string 'true' for example) I cannot save my Controller.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an apex component as above why not we create the checkbox component like below

```
public Boolean chkBox{
    get{
        if(myMap.get(myList[i]) == true){
            return true;
        } 
            return false;            
    }
    set;
```

On the Visualforce page we can write as below

```
<apex:outputLabel value="Check Box Label"/>    <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!chkBox}"><apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="TheBlock" status="showCredentialing" />
```

The Error may also be due to some other Output field ERROR present on the visual force page since VF Errors do not have line numbers.

I tried to implement an independent  Component.Apex.inputCheckbox in a visualforce page. Please try the below code

**CONTROLLER**

```
            public class testcontroller {
        public Component.Apex.inputCheckbox chkBox { get; set; }
        public Component.Apex.inputCheckbox dyCheckbox; 
        public PageReference chkBox3() {
           this.chkBox = new Component.Apex.inputCheckbox();
           System.debug('Here is Test');
           this.chkBox.value = true;     
           return null; 
           }
        public String chkBox2 { get; set; }
        public testcontroller(){
           this.chkBox2 = 'false';
        }
        public Component.Apex.inputCheckbox getInputCheckbox() {
           Component.Apex.inputCheckbox dyCheckbox = new Component.Apex.inputCheckbox();
           dyCheckbox.value = 'true';
           return dyCheckbox;
           }
        }
```

**VISUALFORCE PAGE**

```
<apex:page controller="testcontroller">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page: test 
  <apex:form >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Check Box Label"/>   
     <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!chkBox2}"/>

              <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!InputCheckbox}" />


     <apex:commandButton value="sd" action="{!chkBox3}" title="asdf"/> 
  </apex:form>

  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I use an apex component because I was unable to display my checkboxes the way I need them directly in VF : I need to have a variable number of checkboxes displayed in a table (header + 2 rows of "n" checkboxes). I'm sure that the error comes from "chkBox.selected = true;" : when this line is commented I have no more errors.

Comment: Hi Plato, I tried to implement an independent  Component.Apex.inputCheckbox in a visualforce page. Please try the below code

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I'll give a try to your code : it seems to be the way to the solution.